# How can I create maps in ArcGIS with a Baidu basemap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap, china

I am working on a project mapping select China cities with some automotive related data. The client has requested we show Baidu as the basemap since it is more up-to-date than the OSM basemap we have been using. I have been able to bring in the Baidu basemap into ArcGIS, but I have reason to believe it isn't being displayed properly (at the correct location in relation to a WGS-84 basemap).

Can anyone shed light on this? Perhaps I need to make an adjustment once I bring in this Baidu vector layer to have it render in the right location?

Link to add Baidu basemap:
https://developpaper.com/arcmap-and-arcgis-pro-load-baidu-map/

The first image shows the WGS lat/lon of Tiananmen Square with a green dot and the Baidu lat/lon of Tiananmen Square with a pink square. It is set on the OSM basemap.
[image]

The second image shows the same data points, zoomed out. This will provide context for the third image.
[image]

The third image shows the same data points, now set on the Baidu basemap that I brought in. You can see how far off it is compared to the OSM basemap, and how the pink square does not align with it.
[image]